# Function that counts the number of divisors of a natural number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, arithmetic-functions

Let Function $f(n)$ be formally defined for natural numbers such that it gives number of distinct divisors of the number $n$ ($n$ and $1$ included) For example, $f (12)=6$, then what is a quick way to evaluate  $f(48)$ or $f(2 ^{2013})$? Is there an explicit formula for such an $f(n)$ exist? if yes then what is it?

Comment: Do you know what the prime factorization of a number is? There is a formula based on that. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Properties

Comment: related : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CF.89.28n.29_.E2.80.93_distinct_prime_divisors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that by "parts" of the number you're referring to what's usually called its divisors. These are counted by the [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). An efficient way of finding its values can't be known, since this would yield an efficient way of determining whether a number is prime, and none such is known.

[*Edit:*]

Example calculations based on the prime factorizations of the numbers you asked about:

$48=2^4\cdot3^1$, so $\sigma_0(48)=(4+1)(1+1)=5\cdot2=10$. Also, $\sigma_0(2^{2012})=2012+1=2013$.

The general formula, as given in the Wikipedia article, is $\prod_i(a_i+1)$, where $a_i$ is the exponent of the $i$-th prime in the number's prime factorization.

Comment: yea the meaning is divisors, how i can count f(48) or f(2^2012)?

Comment: @OfirAttia Have you tried the link joriki gave you? You can find there a formula how to compute $\sigma(n)$ once you know the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: i found this and i`m still cannot unserstand it. you can give me some example?

Comment: @Ofir: I added the calculations for your examples.

Comment: so for f(12) it will be 2^2*3^1 = (2+1)*(1+1) - (1+1) -> is the numbers of a(i)? if it will be 2^2*3^1*4^1 so i will write it as (1+1+1)?

Comment: @Ofir: Sorry, I don't understand any of that. I don't know why you're subtracting $(1+1)$, and I don't know how you arrived at $(1+1+1)$. Also, please use $\TeX$ to make your formulas less cumbersome to read. You had already given the correct count $(2+1)(1+1)=3\cdot2=6$ for the first example, $12$, in the question, and I'd already solved the second example, $48$, in the answer. Note that $4$ isn't prime.

Comment: i can do that only with prime numbers?

Comment: @Ofir: Please read the Wikipedia article. It's all in there. Yes, the formula refers to the prime factorization.