# Function with a hash

Tags: number-theory

I have a question involving a function:

$\tau(n) := $#{$d\in\Bbb{Z}>0|$d divides n}

The hash symbol before the first bracket is confusing me, I don't know what this means. And could you please give an example for if I was to substitute in a value for n.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "the number of".  This if $n = 6$, the possibilities for $d$ are $1, 2, 3, 6$, so $\tau(6) = 4$.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense :)

Comment: How would I go about computing $\tau(n)$ if n was a very large number (in the tens of thousands) without manually trying every number?

Comment: Use the prime factorization of $n$.  If $n = p_1^{e_1} \ldots p_k^{e_k}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes, $\tau(n) = (e_1 + 1) \ldots (e_k + 1)$.

Comment: Or you could ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tau(23456)).

Answer (score 1):

It could be the cardinality (number of elements) of the set behind the hash mark. The hash symbol is also used as abbreviation for number: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign).

Comment: So if n was say 10, $\tau(n)$ would be equal to 4? being divisible by 1, 2, 5, and 10

Comment: Yes, the number of positive divisors.

Comment: See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CF.83k.28n.29.2C_.CF.84.28n.29.2C_d.28n.29_.E2.80.93_divisor_sums

Answer (score 0):

The hash symbol denotes the cardinality, e.g. $\#G$ denotes the cardinality of a group $G$, for example $\#(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*=\phi(n)$. Another convention for $\tau(n)$ is to write
$$
\tau(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}1.
$$
This is the more typical way in analytic number theory; another example is
$$
\pi(x)=\sum_{p\le x} 1,
$$
for the prime counting function.

Concerning your question how to compute $\tau(n)$, see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309981/function-that-counts-the-number-of-divisors-of-a-natural-number).